# Need Help: Fragment navigation bug Android 11 and higher

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, crash

I'm developing my application in Android Studio.
Today, I need to upgrade to API33.
Application compilation: OK

Test on my phone :

- Opening : OK
- Navigation inside: OK
- Fragments navigation : Application crash

It's worth noting that during development, I ignored compilation errors:
"This fragment should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)" and "Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead" by adding:

lintOptions {
disable 'ValidFragment'
}

to Gradle. On all Android versions, the application works well except for Api 30 and above.

And what's confusing me is that the application compiled with Api 28 and 29 runs smoothly on all versions of Android 11, 12 and 13. But unfortunately, I have to compile with API33 for Google.

Can you suggest a solution? Or is there an other statement to replace the LintOptions ?

Here's the code for one of my fragments:

```
package com.XXXXXXXX.XXXXX;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HelloFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView lst;
    String[] maladie = {"Michel","Jack"};


    String[] desc = {"Acheteur","Vendeur"};
       


    Integer[] imgid = {R.drawable.michel,R.drawable.jack};

    Activity mainActivity;
    public HelloFragment(Activity main){
        this.mainActivity = main;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.hello_fragment, container, false);


        lst = view.findViewById(R.id.listviewhello);
        CustomeListviewAdapter customeListview = new CustomeListviewAdapter(this.mainActivity,maladie,desc,imgid);
        lst.setAdapter(customeListview);

        lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Michel.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }if(position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),Jack.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

I call from a Home Class :

```
helloFragment = inflate.findViewById(R.id.home_hello);
     helloFragment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             HelloFragment nextFrag= new HelloFragment(getActivity());
             getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag,"findThisFragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
         }
     });
```

Here is on my Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        Signer {
            keyAlias 'ssa_key'
            keyPassword 'XXXXX'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/David/AndroidStudioProjects/ssa_keys.jks')
            storePassword 'YYYYYYY'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        disable 'ValidFragment'
    }


    compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXX'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 14
        versionName "3.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.Signer
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Signer
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildToolsVersion '34.0.0'
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.16'
}
```

I've already tried to compile on several SDK versions 26 to 33, but the same.

Answer (score 0):

the `position` is within the bounds of your data (assuming yourDataList is the list you are displaying in the ListView). If the position is out of bounds, you can either handle it as needed or simply ignore it. This will help prevent a crash when an invalid position is clicked.

you can use `getApplication()` instead of `getContext()` application is more safe.

checkout this

```
        lst.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // Check if the position is within the bounds of your data
                if (position >= 0 && position < yourDataList.size()) {
                    // Create an intent based on the clicked item
                    Intent intent;
                    if (position == 0) {
                        intent = new Intent(/* you can use getApplication()*/getContext(), Michel.class);
                    } else if (position == 1) {
                        intent = new Intent(/* you can use getApplication()*/getContext(), Jack.class);
                    } else {
                        // Handle other positions or show a message that the option is not available
                        // You can also log an error here
                        return;
                    }

                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```